# Qt C++ Error when drawing a simple polygon

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qpolygon

I have an old c++ program that I need to bring back to life. My task now is to draw a single Polygon. I am stuck at the very beginning since I have no experience in graphics. The points I want to use to draw a Polygen are stored in

**QVector < QPointF> points** which looks like that:

[image]

Now I want to draw my Polygon. I use this code:

```
            ggScene = new QGraphicsScene();   
            QPolygonF shape(points);
            QGraphicsItem* gg = ggScene->addPolygon(shape);
```

When compiling I get the following error:

**cannot convert QGraphicsPolygonItem* to QGraphiscItem in initialization**

Can anybiody help me on this please, thank you.

Comment: are you sure this is the correct error message and code? I would expect that error for eg `QGraphicsItem gg = ggScene->addPolygon(shape);`. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I also get   Cannot convert QGraphicsPolygonItem* to QGraphicsItem in initialization

Comment: "also" ? Only you get the error and only you know what is the code, to get help you need to provide a [mcve]. `QGraphicsPolygonItem` inherits from `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem` which inherits from `QGraphicsItem`, hence your code should be fine, but the error is about converting a `QGraphicsPolygonItem*` (pointer) to a  `QGraphicsItem` (object) and there is no such conversion in the code you show

Comment: You should include <QGraphicsItem>, it seems that QGraphicsItem is forward declared somewhere but not known by the compiler at the line of assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the actual error message is...

> cannot convert ‘QGraphicsPolygonItem*’ to ‘QGraphicsItem*’ in
>   initialization

(Note `QGraphicsItem*` rather than just `QGraphicsItem`)

If that's the case then the problem is probably that the compiler is only seeing a forward declaration of `QGraphicsPolygonItem`.  Hence it is not aware that `QGraphicsPolygonItem` inherits from `QGraphicsItem` and so cannot perform the implicit conversion from `QGraphicsPolygonItem*` to `QGraphicsItem*`.

The fix is probably the simple addition of...

```
#include <QGraphicsPolygonItem>
```